# jQuery UI and Closure Compiler Advanced Optimizations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to use Closure Compiler with Advanced Optimizations with my project, I am using jQuery 1.11.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.4.

As extern for jQuery I found an extern of jQuery 1.9 that I think is going to work fine, but I'm having problems with jQuery UI, I am not able to find any extern for any version.

Knows anyonye any extern of jQuery UI?

Thank you.

PS: I tried with the webpage http://www.dotnetwise.com/Code/Externs/ but the extern generated is not helping :-/

Answer (score 3):

I have had luck with creating my own simple externs file.  For instance, if I am only using .draggable and .resizable, this is what it contains:

```html
jQuery.prototype.resizable = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) { };
$.prototype.resizable = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) { };
jQuery.prototype.draggable = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) { };
$.prototype.draggable = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) { };
```

And then in my .js file, use quoted strings instead of dot notation for the property names when initializing:

```html
// USE THIS:
$(".draggable").draggable({ "axis":"x", "containment": "parent", 
        "cursor":"move", "handle":".dragHandle", "snap":"#banner, .draggable", "snapMode":"outer"
    });
//INSTEAD OF THIS:
    $(".draggable").draggable({ axis:"x", containment: "parent", 
        cursor:"move", handle:".dragHandle", snap:"#banner, .draggable", snapMode:"outer"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

No known extern for jQuery UI exists.